# Display accordion icon in vertically middle position

Tags: javascript, accordion

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile_toggle");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var toggle_content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (toggle_content.style.maxHeight) {
      toggle_content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      toggle_content.style.maxHeight = toggle_content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.mobile_toggle {
    padding: 5px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 15px;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.toggle_content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
.mobile_toggle:active i {
 -ms-transform: rotate(50deg); /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(50deg);
}
.active, .mobile_toggle:hover {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
.mobile_toggle:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size:20px
 }
.active:after {
 content: "\2212";
}
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile_toggle">
<span>Our hardcover books are library bound with exposed reinforced endsheets, which means extra lasting power Will your books and materials with?  </span>
</div>
  <div class="toggle_content">
    <p>Our hardcover books are library bound with exposed reinforced endsheets, which means extra lasting power, use after use. They are side sewn or section sewn, and all covers are laminated with glossy film. The books are vibrant, durable, and unconditionally guaranteed. </p>
  </div>
```

I created this accordion for mobile visitors only. If I use a long title I can't change the after icon position.

I want to display the icon in middle of the accordion title!

If it's not possible with after icon is there any way to use an image/SVG for the same function.

Thanks
Suman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible to do this with your `::after` element. You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to easily align content, this also has effect on `::before` and `::after` elements. In your case you can add the following `CSS` snippet to your `.mobile_toggle` class to align the icon in the middle of the title.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

I have also edited your snippet to see this change in full.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile_toggle");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var toggle_content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (toggle_content.style.maxHeight) {
      toggle_content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      toggle_content.style.maxHeight = toggle_content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.mobile_toggle {
    padding: 5px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 15px;
 transition: 0.5s;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.toggle_content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
.mobile_toggle:active i {
 -ms-transform: rotate(50deg); /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(50deg);
}
.active, .mobile_toggle:hover {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
.mobile_toggle:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size:20px
 }
.active:after {
 content: "\2212";
}
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile_toggle">
<span>Our hardcover books are library bound with exposed reinforced endsheets, which means extra lasting power Will your books and materials with?  </span>
</div>
  <div class="toggle_content">
    <p>Our hardcover books are library bound with exposed reinforced endsheets, which means extra lasting power, use after use. They are side sewn or section sewn, and all covers are laminated with glossy film. The books are vibrant, durable, and unconditionally guaranteed. </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks Luze, I want to align it vertically middle like this: https://codepen.io/vadimhimself/pen/gOYweNo

Comment: @SumanBhadra Oh sorry, looks like I misinterpreted your question. In that case just remove the `flex-direction: column` part and you should be good to go. I have updated my answer and snippet to match your request.

Answer (score 1):

Why not trying something like this? I hope this serves the purpose and I did understand your q. Please provide more info on how you want to position the `after` icon.

I only added the following CSS. I "removed" the existing `float` as we want to center the icon.

**Update:** I leave the original solution here. The OP clarified what is actually needed so I'm also with the flex approach proposed by @luze to vertical align the + and - buttons.

```
.mobile-toggle:after, .active::after {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile_toggle");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var toggle_content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (toggle_content.style.maxHeight) {
      toggle_content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      toggle_content.style.maxHeight = toggle_content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.mobile_toggle {
    padding: 5px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 15px;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.toggle_content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
.mobile_toggle:active i {
 -ms-transform: rotate(50deg); /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(50deg);
}
.active, .mobile_toggle:hover {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
.mobile_toggle:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size:20px;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
 }
.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile_toggle">
<span>Our hardcover books are library bound with exposed reinforced endsheets, which means extra lasting power Will your books and materials with?  </span>
</div>
  <div class="toggle_content">
    <p>Our hardcover books are library bound with exposed reinforced endsheets, which means extra lasting power, use after use. They are side sewn or section sewn, and all covers are laminated with glossy film. The books are vibrant, durable, and unconditionally guaranteed. </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I want something like this https://codepen.io/vadimhimself/pen/gOYweNo 

As you can see the icon position in the middle, if I use a big title it still remains in the same position

Comment: @SumanBhadra I misunderstood your question. So I'm also with luze's solution.